# How to update the existing sticker pack of Whatsapp

Tags: java, flutter, react-native, kotlin, whatsapp

I have written codes for adding sticker pack dynamically. But I want to know how to update the sticker pack after adding to whatsapp?
I can add sticker file to the pack which is listed on my app only but it is not reflecting in whatsapp. I tried adding files to the same location (file:///...) from where the pack was sent to whatsapp.
I want to try updating content provider. But how to do that? Can I add files to whatsapp's 'content://...' uri or should I update my app's content provider or anything else?
I am using react-native-whatsapp-stickers module for react-native.

react-native code

```js
invoking after adding single sticker from UI
const addOne = (path, packName) =>{
    // log('path ',path[0])
    // log('packName ',packName)
    RNWhatsAppStickers.addSticker(path[0],packName)
    .then(res=>RNWhatsAppStickers.send(packName,packName))
    .then(res=>console.log('response ',res))
}
```

Java code of module RNWhatsAppStickers

```java
 @ReactMethod
    public void send(String identifier, String stickerPackName, Promise promise) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.whatsapp.intent.action.ENABLE_STICKER_PACK");
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID, identifier);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_AUTHORITY, getContentProviderAuthority(reactContext));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_NAME, stickerPackName);

        try {
            Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
            ResolveInfo should = activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0);
            if (should != null) {
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_PACK);
                promise.resolve("OK");
            } else {
                promise.resolve("OK, but not opened");
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            promise.reject(ERROR_ADDING_STICKER_PACK, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            promise.reject(ERROR_ADDING_STICKER_PACK, e);
        }
    }

// saving image to same pack
public static void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String name, String identifier) {

        String root = path + "/" + identifier;
        File myDir = new File(root);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = name;
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()){
            // Log.d("ReactNative","root "+root);
            file.delete();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please give any idea what to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on official doc. You have to increase the `image_data_Version` for that pack after adding new images.
To track the `image_data_Version` you can query the ContentProvider of your app or Store the `image_data_Version` somewhere and make changes accordingly .

Comment: which changes needed to do this?

Comment: While passing the json data you have to set the version of pack. If you do not know about version key of json data then please check out the official repo. They have added the version key later.